# find linked stylesheets with jquery and add a random number at the end

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all stylesheet to look like:

```
<link href="style.css?v=1234" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The only problem I'm running into is getting the current link tag and then applying the new random number to the current path.  I think my method of applying finding the link is ok, but getting the current attr and then applying a new one is where I'm going wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
// is this the best way?
$("head").find("link").attr("href")+"?v="+randomNum;

// I don't think this works
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').end()+"?v="+randomNum;

});
```

I have a bunch of people who are experiencing cache problems and they noted that this would be a possible solution.

Comment: Hmm why do you want to do this??
The stylesheet will be pulled in before this javascript runs so your giong to pull in the file with out the query string

Comment: As you must know I'm loading this into a browser extension so it happens before the css is loaded on page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were not setting the value back to the link. You can use a function to set the link value like below.

```
$("head").find("link").attr("href", function (i, value) {
   return value +"?v="+randomNum;
});
```

Comment: This pulls in all links, not just style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have people experiencing cache problems with new files try the following approach:

- add a version number to the css file
- everytime you deploy a new CSS file update the version number (dont forget to update the reference to it aswell)

That way people will always see the corresponding css for the page they have loaded and you can still benefit from browser cache

e.g. style-1.0.css

Comment: Query string is sufficient and saves having to update *two* places. However, doing it after the entire document has loaded, as OP is trying, is not going to work. =)

Comment: True, but with version numbers if users have the html content cached they will see the old css stylesheet. That way the page never breaks, they either see all the latest code or all the old code

Comment: If they see the old HTML content, the link to the CSS will have an older query string which will correspond to an older cached CSS as well, so it'll work out. Your answer is, of course, also a viable solution if OP feels they can maintain CSS versions. =)